# Laravel & LaravelCollective HTML/Forms Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I'm building a simple form with a username and password.

When I construct a username field like this:

```
{{ Form::text('username') }}
```

My page loads without issue. As soon as I want to define a class like this:

```
{{ Form::text('username', ['class' => 'awesome']) }}
```

I get an error, like so:

```
ErrorException in HtmlBuilder.php line 65:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Haven't been able to find any info regarding this error online. These examples are taken STRAIGHT from the LaravelCollective documentation.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the class in the third parameter like so:

```
{{ Form::text('username', null, ['class' => 'awesome']) }}
```

or:

```
{{ Form::text('username', '', ['class' => 'awesome']) }}
```

The second parameter is the value field

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Why is this not defined in the documentation?? lmao. https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#text

Comment: it is defined bro check **Custom Component** section

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 5 You should write like this:

```
{!! Form::text() !!}
```

Not like this:

```
{{ Form::text() }}
```

Also you have attributes array given as second parameter which is default value of this input. Please change it to:

```
{!! Form::text('your_name', null, ['class' => 'someclass']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/5.4/src/FormBuilder.php#L279-L291), the expected parameters are:

```
Form::text($name, $value = null, $options = [])
```

The second parameter is for specifying a default value for the form element. So to define a class, you should pass the array to the third parameter:

```
Form::text('username', null, ['class' => 'awesome'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel 5.4 
you shouldn't use double curly for laravel collective html form like this

```
{{ Form::() }}
```

try this instead

```
{!! Form::text('username', $value = null, ['class' => 'awesome']) !!}
```